# How to compile an ASP.NET Visual Studio project in PowerShell 5

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.0

In Command Prompt, I would use:

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_compiler -p "C:\Visual Studio 2013\myProjectFolder" -v /-u "C:\CompiledFilesFolder"
```

Comment: This should also work in PowerShell. What error do you get?

Comment: Not getting an error, Martin, thanks. Just wondered if it could be done - and how - in PowerShell.

Comment: How do I thank you here?

Comment: I will add an answer which you can accept using the green checkmark.

Comment: Yes, it works! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code will *also work in* [powershell](/questions/tagged/powershell). Here is a slightly improved way to do it:

```
$aspnetCompiler = (Join-Path $env:windir 'Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_compiler')
& $aspnetCompiler -p "C:\Visual Studio 2013\myProjectFolder" -v /-u "C:\CompiledFilesFolder"
```